# Connect from Docker to Local Host

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a docker container basically running Athena Tool Kit for PDF generation. The service in docker in turn calls a NodeJs Application at this URL: - http://localhost:3005.

However I see a message on Docker Console:-

```
[GIN] 2019/08/23 - 22:24:46 | 500 |    1.850464ms |    192.168.99.1 |  GET     /convert
Error #01: Get http://localhost:3005/presentations/d0161fed-0ade-40a5-8dff-26696e553e96?id=d0161fed-0ade-40a5-8dff-26696e553e96&type=box-upload&params=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3005: connect: connection refused
captured errors:
Error #01: Get http://localhost:3005/presentations/d0161fed-0ade-40a5-8dff-26696e553e96?id=d0161fed-0ade-40a5-8dff-26696e553e96&type=box-upload&params=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3005: connect: connection refused.
```

The Docker Service runs locally at http://192.168.99.100:8080. From this address it is trying to call  127.0.0.1:3005. When it does I get the error above.

I am guessing this must be allowing access to local host from a different IP.

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Comment: Can you show how you start up the docker container?

Comment: @Max - docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -it  patelsan/presentations-pdf-toolkit:1.0.1

Comment: both containers in the same network ?

Comment: @Thammer - Both of them on my local machine. But I think the docker service has a different IP(http://192.168.99.100:8080.)

Comment: what do you mean by your local machine = host machine of your containers? can you share your docker-compose file, please

Comment: @Thamer - The Docker runs in my own local machine.

Comment: as I can see you are running your tow containers without docker-compose file instead with docker cli, please provide a clear description of how many containers you are using and how have you lanched them, in that way we can find a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198394/discussion-between-thamer-and-saiband).

Answer (score 0):

as I can see, you are running to applications, the first one is  `patelsan/presentations-pdf-toolkit` with a docker container and the second one is a nodejs application within your host.

> your problem here that the two application running in two different
>   networks, the host network for nodejs app and the docker bridge
>   default network as a default network for your container.

otherwise as mentioned in Docker doc [Docker network host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) :

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not
>   supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or
>   Docker EE for Windows Server.

I have 3 solutions for both local and prod environments:

1. Local env:

as a local env solution, you can assign the `patelsan/presentations-pdf-toolkit` container to the default `host`  network in the docker, in this way both applications can communicate with each other:

```
 - run the `patelsan/presentations-pdf-toolkit` container:
 - `docker network connect host container_name`
```

2. production env:

you can use [weave net service](https://www.weave.works/) to create a virtual network.

NP:

If your host is Windows or Mac I suggest you containerize the nodejs application as well, with that you can create a new network and your 2 containers can communicate with that network.

Comment: Now after trying your solution I get  dial tcp [::1]:3005: connect: connection refused. What do I need to do now ?

Comment: @SaiBand if your host machine is windows or mac, you cannot use the host docker network as mentioned in my answer above